# Entity framework code first - projection problems

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, projection

I have something like this:

```
var model = forumsDb.Categories
    .Select(c => new {c, c.Threads.Count})
    .ToList()
```

My Category object looks like this (pseudocode):

```
public class Category 
{
     public int id {get;set;}
     public ICollection<Thread> Threads { get; set; }

     /***some properties***/
     [NotMapped]
     public int ThreadCount {get;set;}
}
```

Now, in my model object, i have two items: `model.c` and `model.Count`. How can i map `model.Count` into `model.c.ThreadCount`?

Comment: What model object you mention in here?

Comment: ? I don't understand, the one that is given by a query I posted at top of my post? It actually maps into anonymous type of {Category, int} object.

Comment: I dont see your model have property Count

Comment: Yes, it automatically maps c.Threads.Count, into model.Count after i execute the query, as i said previously, i now want to map this model.Count into model.c.ThreadCount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a strong type:

```
public class YourModel
{
    public YourModel(Category c, int count)
    {
        C = c;
        Count = count;
        c.Threads.Count = count;
    }

    public Category C { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

var model = forumsDb.Categories
    .Select(c => new YourModel(c, c.Threads.Count))
    .ToList()
```

Comment: Now that's something. But I'm getting some errors, just need a second to look at them. :-)

Comment: Well, the edit is an expression tree, so it cannot be converted into linq. But, if i remove this return statement, it underscores the .Select and says that it does not know if it is `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable`, and typing `.Select<IQueryable>(/*code*/)` does nothing, so i guess i'm pretty much stuck up in here. :/ But this code does have something in it, thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

Iterate and assign the value.

```
foreach(var entry in model)
{
    entry.c.ThreadCount = entry.Count;
}

var categories = model.Select(m => m.c);
```

Comment: Yes, this is possible, and i thought of this, but what if i had like 10k categories? This approach is pretty much inefficient, so i am searching for some other solutions. Like, i don't know, telling the entity framework to automatically map it?

Comment: @ojek  you would have to measure in that case. I'd guess the materialization cost would be much higher than the loop. Better to page the results than pull 10k records.