# Including an object with where clause in LINQ

Tags: sql, linq, .net-core

I would like to have a LINQ query that is supposed to return all members with VitalSigns where event in the vital signs is equal to surgery.

My `Member.cs` class:

```
public class Member
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<VitalSign> VitalSigns { get; set; }

    public Member()
    {
         VitalSigns = new Collection<VitalSign>();
    }
}
```

And my `VitalSign.cs` class is :

```
public class VitalSign
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Event { get; set; }

    // relationships
    public Member Member { get; set; }
    public int MemberId { get; set; }
}
```

The LINQ query that I wrote is:

```
 return await context. Members.Include(c => c.VitalSigns.Where(t => t.Event == "post surgery")).ToListAsync();
```

This returns a self-referenced loop. Because there are some data in the `VitalSigns` where the event is not equal to "post surgery". Am I writing the query wrong?

Comment: @RyanWilson The problem isn't the order (`Where` before or after `Include`), the problem is that the `Where` and the `Include` should be at the same level in the query, so the `Where` outside the `Include`

Comment: @xanatos Thanks for the explanation. Appreciate that. I'm still doing my database work using SQLClient and stored procedures, etc. So I'm not very familiar with the EntityFramework with Linq syntax.

Comment: @xanatos if they're in the same level then I can't get Event.

Comment: @gogo Because you have to use an inner `Any`... See my response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query should be:

```
context.Members.Where(t => t.VitalSigns.Any(u => u.Event == "post surgery"))
    .Include(c => c.VitalSigns)
    .ToListAsync()
```

The `Include()` is only an hint on what tables should be loaded when the query is executed.

The query is something like:

```
all the members WHERE there is ANY (at least) one VitalSign with Event == post surgery
together with the Members you'll get, please INCLUDE the VitalSigns (the alternative is that they'll be lazily loaded when you try to access them)
return a List<> (ToListAsync) of the elements in an asynchronous way
```

Comment: Good explanation and thanks for breaking it down from the llambdas to plain linq syntax. +1 from me.

Comment: Well this query returns all the vital signs no matter the event is equal or not equal to "post surgery"

Comment: @GoGo It returns all the Members with at least one vital sign equal to post surgery. The other vital signs are included. [It is a limitation of Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636952/how-to-filter-include-entities-in-entity-framework).

Comment: well, it is not currently possible to filter which related entities are loaded. Include will always bring in all related entities. That's not good.https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#explicitFilter