# Entity Framework - How to get an entity including a filtered collection of child entities

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have categories, and categories have a collection of products (Category.Products). I need to retrieve a category from the db by its id, but instead of including all its products, I want it to only include products with a given condition (example, order=0)

How can I do this with linq?
I tried with:

```
var e = db.Categories
  .Include(a => a.products)
  .Where(a => a.products.Any(r => r.order == 0))
  .FirstOrDefault(p => p.id == id_category);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter "Include" entities in entity framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636952/how-to-filter-include-entities-in-entity-framework)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. In any case, the call to `.Include()` should be after any `where` clause, or it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

In order to filter child collection you can try to select that to `YouCustomModel`or anonymous projection.

> Note that it is not currently possible to filter which related entities are loaded. Include will always bring in all related entities [Msdn reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data#explicitFilter).

```
var e = db.Categories
          .Where(c => c.id == id_category)
          .Select(p=> new 
          { 

             category = p,
             products = p.Products.Where(k=>k.order==0)
          }.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score -1):

var e = db.Categories.Where(a => a.order == 0);

Comment: This will only retrieve some categories, but won't include any products in the result. Not to mention it doesn't fit the described schema.