# Filtering "include" entities in EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following models

```
 public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<PersonRole> PersonRoles { get; set; }

}

public class RoleInDuty
{
    public int roleInDutyId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int typeOfDutyId { get; set; }
    public TypeOfDuty typeOfDuty { get; set; }
    public List<PersonRole> PersonRoles { get; set; }

}
public class PersonRole
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public int RoleInDutyId { get; set; }
    public RoleInDuty RoleInDuty { get; set; }
}
```

And now I can load all people with all their roles using the following code:

```
 var  people = _context.Persons
      .Include(p => p.PersonRoles)
        .ThenInclude(e => e.RoleInDuty).ToList();
```

But I wantn't load all data to List, I need load PersonRole according entered typeOfDutyId.
I am trying to solve this with the following code

```
people = _context.Persons
  .Include(p => p.PersonRoles
    .Where(t=>t.RoleInDuty.typeOfDutyId == Id)).ToList();
```

But VS throw error

> InvalidOperationException: The Include property lambda expression 'p
>   => {from PersonRole t in p.PersonRoles where ([t].RoleInDuty.typeOfDutyId == __typeOfDuty_typeOfDutyId_0) select
>   [t]}' is invalid. The expression should represent a property access:
>   't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types,
>   specify an explicitly typed lambda parameter of the target type, E.g.
>   '(Derived d) => d.MyProperty'. For more information on including
>   related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

As I understand I can't access property **RoleInDuty.typeOfDutyId** because i'm not include it yet.

I solved this problem with the following code

```
people = _context.Persons
  .Include(p => p.PersonRoles)
    .ThenInclude(e=>e.RoleInDuty).ToList();       
foreach (Person p in people)
{
  p.PersonRoles = p.PersonRoles
    .Where(e => e.RoleInDuty.typeOfDutyId == Id)
    .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter "Include" entities in entity framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636952/how-to-filter-include-entities-in-entity-framework)

Comment: Did you try explicitly typing the lambda in the where clause?  (PersonRole t) => t.RoleInDuty.typeOfDutyId == Id

Comment: The way you have solved it is really bad. You are getting all the data from the db loading them in memory and doing the filter which defeats the point of the query. Neverthless your  query sounds like it could be better in reverse. Why don't you Query the PersonRoles for the typeofDutyId then include the Person on that query so you ahve all the matching PersonRoles with their personrs

Comment: @Рома Матковский although you have solved the issue anyway but please take a look into my answer. It will surely help you. Thank you.

Comment: @Neil.Work i tried it, don't work to

Comment: @npo I try to do so, but as result I get Collection of PersonRoles and where each PersonRole has one Person. But I need return IEnumerable<Person> to my View

Comment: @devNull It's useful, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[devnull](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5803406/devnull) show the next  [How to filter "Include" entities in entity framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636952/how-to-filter-include-entities-in-entity-framework), and there the same problem, I read it, and find the answer. Solve my problem can with the next:

```
var temp = _context.Persons.Select(s => new
  {
    Person = s,
    PersonRoles= s.PersonRoles
      .Where(p => p.RoleInDuty.typeOfDutyId == this.typeOfDuty.typeOfDutyId)
      .ToList()
  }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Finally, filter in Include with ef core 5. Details in MSDN doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#filtered-include

```
Var people = _context.Persons
                     .Include(p => p.PersonRoles
                                    .Where(t=>t.RoleInDuty.typeOfDutyId == Id))
                     .ToList();

var blogs = context.Blogs
                   .Include(e => e.Posts.OrderByDescending(post => post.Title).Take(5)))
                   .ToList();
```