# Is filtering inside Include function not allowed in LINQ Expressions. Nested while inside Include

Tags: linq, filter, nested, iqueryable, any

I am not getting filtered record as expected as mentioned in below query. Also I need to perform this as Queryable

I have tried using Include and tried to filter it with Where inside Include itself as a subquery. But of no success.

```
query.Where(task => ( task.Audit.OrderBy(t => t.OccurredAt).Take(1).Any(p=> (DateFrom.HasValue? p.OccurredAt>= DateFrom:true ) && (DateTo.HasValue? p.OccurredAt <=DateTo:true))));
```

Here query is a Queryable expression!!

**Expected:** Need to get the filtered date as per Date range given in Iqueryable format
**Actual:** Getting all records

Comment: I assume you are using some (what?) version of Entity Framework?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter "Include" entities in entity framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636952/how-to-filter-include-entities-in-entity-framework)