# Complex LINQ query - multiple table relationships

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a books database, which has an ICollection of authors. I want to return the author object based on the AuthorId using LINQ.

```
Book db

int BookId
string Name { get; set; }
public ICollection<Author> Authors { get; set; }

Author db
int AuthorId
string Name
ICollection<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }
ICollection<Penname> Pennames { get; set; } - Edit: Added for clarity
```

I have tried:

```
var test = _context.Book.Include(x => x.Authors).Include("Authors.Quotes")
                    .Select(y => y.Authors)
```

Which gave me:

```
EntityQueryable<ICollection<Authors>>
[0] {HashSet<Author>} [0]{Author} [1]{Author} [3]{Author} 
[1] {HashSet<Author>} [0]{Author} [1]{Author} 
[2] {HashSet<Author>} [0]{Author} [1]{Author}
```

I just can't figure out how to iterate though the Authors in the Authors list. Something like the below:

```
var id = 2

var test = _context.Book.Include(x => x.Authors).Include("Authors.Quotes")
                    .Select(y => y.Authors.Select(x => x.Author).Where(x => x.AuthorId == id))
```

If I ever do a major update I might use elastic...

Update @Marko Papic:

Thanks. Weirdly if I use the below to get a list of books with authors, I get the quotes and pennames lists populated as I expect

```
var test = _context.Book.Include(x => x.Authors)
                   .ThenInclude(x => x.Quotes)
                   .Include(x => x.Authors)
                   .ThenInclude(x => x.Pennames)
```

However if I use SelectMany, then the quotes and pennames end up as null

```
var test = _context.Book.Include(x => x.Authors)
                   .ThenInclude(x => x.Quotes)
                   .Include(x => x.Authors)
                   .ThenInclude(x => x.Pennames)
                   .SelectMany(x => x.Authors).Where(x => x.AuthorId == id);

Author myauthor
int AuthorId = 2
string Name = "Bob"
ICollection<Quote> Quotes = null
ICollection<Penname> Pennames = null
```

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Comment: I ran dotnet ef --version and got Entity Framework Core .NET Command-line Tools 2.2.4-servicing-10062. This is with ASP.NET Core 2.2

Comment: If you want to return the `Author` object with a particular `AuthorId`, why bother with `Books`? Just use `_context.Authors.First(a => a.AuthorId == AuthorId)`.

Comment: If what you are trying to do is filter the `Authors` collection attached to a `Book`, you can't do that. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39636952/2557128) for example.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-2.2):

```cs
var test = _context.Book.Include(x => x.Authors).ThenInclude(x => x.Quotes)
                    .SelectMany(x => x.Authors).Where(x => x.AuthorId == id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the includes are ignored because the result type of the query is not the same of the type of your dbset with when you start, from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#ignored-includes):

> If you change the query so that it no longer returns instances of the
>   entity type that the query began with, then the include operators are
>   ignored.

I assume the relationship between `Books` and `Authors` is many to many, if that is the case then this is how I would do your query:

```
var query=_context.Authors.Include(a=>a.Books)
                          .Include(a=>a.Quotes)
                          .Include(a=>a.Pennames)
                          .Where(a=> a.AuthorId == id);
```

Comment: `Authors` doesn't appear to have a `Books` collection?

Comment: Well, I think he is omitting that, the OP also doesn't show that `Authors` has `Pennames` and he is using it in the query. That should be just part of the model

Comment: Im confused - I added pennames to the db model  above to make it clearer (it is the same as a quote). Books contains a collection of authors, which contains a collection of quotes and pennames.

Comment: Do you know if the relationship between Authors and Books is many to many? If that is the case how is represented in your model? Through a junction table or directly between both entities?