# Extracting list of lists from Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Say, that I have the following entities defined:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Surname { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Entry> Entries { get; set; }
}

public class Entry
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public virtual long Timestamp { get; set; }
    public virtual string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to retrieve:

- A list of **all** users
- With a list of entries for each user (with empty list if the user has no entries)
- With entries' Timestamp being between values X and Y

Obviously I can dump Users and Entries tables and organize data by myself, but that would be very inefficient. Is there a way to generate such a result with Entity Framework query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter "Include" entities in entity framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636952/how-to-filter-include-entities-in-entity-framework)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot filter an `Include` expression unfortunately, so you will have to create a projection - if there aren't that many properties, it's not too tedious.

```
   var users = from user in context.Users
     select new User { 
        Name = user.Name,
        Surname = user.Surname,
        Entries = user.Entries.Where(u => u.Timestamp > X && u.Timestamp < Y).ToList()
     }
```

Comment: This one seems to suit my needs best. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work as far as i see in your question:

```
var users = context.Users
    // exclue this where caluse if you want the user to be loaded anyway
    .Where(c => c.Entries.Any(i => i.Timestamp >= X && i.Timestamp <= Y))
    .Select(c => new
    {
        User = c,
        Entries = c.Entries.Where(i => i.Timestamp >= X && i.Timestamp <= Y))
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this by using your database context. I assuming that your database context is using eager loading so you can do something like this:

```
_yourDataBaseContext.Set<User>()
.Select(it=> new User
{
     Name = it.Name,
     Surname = it.Surname,
     Entries = it.Entries.ToList().Where(e=> e.Timestamp > x && e.Timestamp <y)
})
.Include("Entries")
.ToList();
```

Comment: That gets Users that have _any_ entry with a timestamp within the range, but includes _all_ their entries.

Answer (score -1):

A list of all users

```
_dbContext.Users();
```

With list of entries for each user (with empty list if user has no entries)

```
 using System.Data.Entity;

_dbContext.Users().Include(x => x.Entries);
```

With entries' Timestamp being between values X and Y

```
using System.Data.Entity;

_dbContext.Users().Where(x => x.Entries.Any(y => y.Timestamp >= X && i.Timestamp <= Y))
.Select(c => new
{
    User = c,
    Entries = c.Entries.Where(x => x.Timestamp >= X && x.Timestamp <= Y))
}).ToList();
```

Comment: EF doesn't support filtered Includes.