# C# Entityframework how to add where clause to the include child collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following method to get a person detail by id.  I want to add where condition to the include ie. `Where(subordinates => subordinates.Active)`  . Can anyone help me how to do this?

```
public async Task<PersonDetails> GetPerson(int id)
    {
        var hasSensitiveAccess = _permissionsService.GetSensitiveAccess();

        return await _context.User
            .Include(user => user.Manager)
            .Include(user => user.InverseManager) //want to include only active subordinates
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(user => user.Id == id)
            .Select(UserDetailsMappingSelector.ToViewModel(hasSensitiveAccess))
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter "Include" entities in entity framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636952/how-to-filter-include-entities-in-entity-framework)

Answer (score 0):

```
return await _context.User
            .Include(user => user.Manager)
            .Include(user => user.InverseManager.Where(s => s.Active))
            .ThenInclude(s => s.Manager)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(user => user.Id == id)
```

Comment: .Include(user => user.InverseManager) this is a collection. i am trying to filter only active list here