# Entity Framework Core filter query with aggregate functions in the Database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have an entity `Projekt` with many related entities that have to be included.
I want to filter these `Projekte` with the filter clause in the `where` statement.
Unfortunately, it doesn't let me do this without calling `.ToList()` first which means, that all the `Projekt` with all the related entities are loaded first which is a performance problem.

How is is possible to filter the entities with the where-clause before calling .ToList() so that it is filtered on the database instead of inmemory?

```
var projekteWithBudgetUeberschreitung = this.db.Projekt
            .Include(x => x.ProjektMitarbeiter)
            .Include(x => x.ProjektPhase)
            .ThenInclude(x => x.ProjektPhaseResource)
            .Include(x => x.ProjektIstWerte)
            .Include(x => x.ProjektStatus)
            .ToList()
            .Where(x => Math.Abs(x.ProjektIstWerte.Sum(y => y.ProjektkostenIst_CHF) ?? 0) >= (decimal)0.75 * Math.Abs(x.PersonalExternPlan_CHF_Freigegeben))
            .ToList();
```

thanks in advance

Comment: afaik, there is no trivial way to filter the `Include`-d rows, please see [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636952/how-to-filter-include-entities-in-entity-framework).

Comment: Which exception do you have? Which EF version? EF Core should translate `Math.Abs` function.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I'm using EFCore 3.1.13. The exception is: `'The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Projekt>
    .Where(p => Math.Abs(DbSet<ProjektIstWerte>
        .Where(p0 => EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(p, "Id") != null && EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(p, "Id") == EF.Property<Nullable<Guid>>(p0, "ProjektId"))
        .Sum(p0 => p0.ProjektkostenIst_CHF) ?? 0) >= 0.75 * Math.Abs(p.PersonalExternPlan_CHF_Freigegeben))' could not be translated.`

Comment: Try to discover which part of predicate causes this exception. Just simplify filter and find problematic part.

Comment: To further help debugging, use `optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(ILoggerFactory);` in your dbcontext to see the generated sql