# LINQ .NET can't filter on .include .select .where to filter collection on deeply nested object

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am stuck on filtering a returning collection with deeply nested objects with the the following code

```
var my collection = await myRepository.GetDBSet<MyObjectType>()
                    .include(x => Table1)
                    .include(x => Table2)
                    .include(x => Table2.Select(y => SubTable1))
                    .include(x => Table2.Select(y => SubTable1.Users))
                    .include(x => Table2.Select(y => SubTable1.Users.Addressess))
                    .include(x => Table2.Select(y => SubTable1.Users.Roles))
                    .include(x => Table2.Select(y => SubTable1.Users.Departments))
                    .Where(w => w.id1 = _id && w.isActive = t);
```

This example query works, please ignore the .where clause

I want to filter the SubTable1.Users.Departments and not bring back any departs with deptId != 1

Here is what I tried on the .where section

```
.Where(w => w.id1 = _id && w.isActive = t &&
w.Table2.where(s => s.SubTable1.Users.Departments.First().DeptId != 1))
```

This does not work, the error is saying it cannot convert int to bool. I had to add the .First() since it would not allow the DeptId.  I am trying to filter out any dept record that has the deptId but not sure how to do this on a deeply nested linq statement.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is `w.Table2.where` doing? You could simply replace `where` with `Any`, and `First` with `Any` as well, and move `DeptId != 1` under second `Any`

Comment: Which ORM do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using LINQ's **[Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-7.0)**?

From Microsoft's documentation:

> Determines whether any element of a sequence exists or satisfies a
> condition.

In your example it shuld be something like this:

```
.Where(w => w.id1 = _id && w.isActive = t &&
w.Table2.where(s => s.SubTable1.Users.Departments.Any(x => x.DeptId != 1))
```

Comment: This would filter the base objects (`MyObjectType`) on the given condition, but still include all the Departments as long as one of them has ID of 1.

Comment: yes, get an error Operator && cannot be applied to operands of type bool and IEnumerable<Table2>

Answer (score 0):

*(Below I assume that your question contains pseudocode and answer accordingly, since your code normally wouldn't compile. I also assume you're using EF Core.)*

You can theoretically do it within the `Include` statement like this:

```
var my collection = await myRepository.GetDBSet<MyObjectType>()
                    .Include(...)
                    ...
                    .Include(x => x.Table2)
                        .ThenInclude(y => y.SubTable1)
                        .ThenInclude(z => z.Users)
                        .ThenInclude(t => t.Departments.Where(d => d.Id == 1))
                    ...
                    .Where(w => w.id1 = _id && w.isActive = t);
```

From my experience the support for such syntax in EF Core is a bit underwhelming - for example, it only allows **one** such condition per LINQ query - but this is still the simplest way to filter out the related records that you don't need *and* select the original, tracked entities from the database.

This feature is called Filtered Include and is available starting from EF Core 5.0 ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include))

Comment: I am not using Core, there is no .ThenInclude

Comment: I did try .include(x => Table2.Select(y => SubTable1.Users.Departments.where(s => s.deptId != 1))) but that did not work either

Comment: @c0micrage Then you might want to check this question and answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636952/how-to-filter-include-entities-in-entity-framework